# Background image gets squashed in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I am currently implementing a form with a custom UIID that has a background image set to `scaled`.

The background image gets squashed when the keyboard opens on android. This creates an unbearable user experience.

How can I prevent this? I want the keyboard to slide over the background or push the whole UI up, not resizing the screen. I recall Steve recently implemented some Android fixes for this, but it seems they do not occur on the latest plugin.

Please find my component hierarchy below. Note that the centre container containing the textfields is Scrollable:

[image: component hierarchy]

Answer (score 2):

I have just found a temporary fix for the components getting squashed Android issue.

I changed the Form UIID from **Image_Scaled** to **Image_Scaled_Fill**.

When a TextField gets selected the background moves slightly, but that is more bearable...

Comment: That would have been my advice. Android resizes the screen to make components fit into place. This is something we hope to improve in the future.